# Android Crashlytics stopped sending crash reports

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I've got Firebase Crashlytics set up in Android app. Yesterday it worked and I received crash reports. Today, however, I don't receive crash reports anymore.

I noticed the following error in the logs, which seems to be related:

```
19511 19511 E CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
03-19 14:17:03.406 19511 19511 E CrashlyticsCore: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
03-19 14:17:03.406 19511 19511 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
03-19 14:17:03.406 19511 19511 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
03-19 14:17:03.406 19511 19511 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:321)
03-19 14:17:03.406 19511 19511 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:301)
03-19 14:17:03.406 19511 19511 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:42)
03-19 14:17:03.406 19511 19511 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
03-19 14:17:03.406 19511 19511 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
03-19 14:17:03.406 19511 19511 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1955)
```

How can I fix Crashlytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what happened here, but after updating all my dependencies (incl. Gradle stuff) the issue was resolved.

Maybe it was a bug in Crashlytics, or some misalignment of dependencies versions...